# Пустота между элементами

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, появилась вот такая пустота между блоками, я нашел на форуме подобную тему, но перед тем как пытаться пробовать плагин masorny хотелось бы узнать может кто знает как это исправить.

```css
.contacts_with_map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(../img/map.jpg);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -175px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}

.map_cover {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  top: -110px;
  position: relative;
}

.contactsForm {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 423px;
  left: 47.7%;
  top: -25px;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: 110px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 330px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 5px 25px 8px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 25px 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffad1e;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
}

.contactsForm_ftext1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 33px 15px 0px 15px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.contactsForm_ftext2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 15px 25px 20px 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid green;
  /*top: -300px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts_with_map">
  <div>
    <div class="map_cover"><img src="img/map_cover.jpg" /></div>
    <form class="contactsForm">
      <span class="contactsForm_ftext1">Остались вопросы?</span> <span class="contactsForm_ftext2">Заполните форму ниже и наши менеджеры свяжутся с Вами!</span>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя*">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Ваш телефон*">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail*">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="div_num">
    <span class="call_now_text">Звоните прямо сейчас:</span>
    <div class="phone_numbers">
      <span class="nums_1">+38 (048) 965 32 45 <br> +38 (099) 256 75 32</span>
      <span class="nums_2">+38 (048) 965 32 45 <br> +38 (099) 256 75 32</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="footer_logo"><img src="img/footer_logo.png"></div>
  <div class="footer_copywrite"><span> © 2016 Кровля профи.  Все права защищены. Сайт разработан: AVADA-MEDIA</span></div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же сами указали в селекторе:

```
.contacts_with_map{
   top: -175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема тут `.contacts_with_map` у вас задано `top: -175px;`